# Excel VBA breaking from Sub call

Tags: vba, excel

I have a ChartObject named "GFATMEN" that needs to update the legend when I check some form control Checkboxes in a Spreadsheet. They are being used so I can show or not some data on the chart, and I need the legend to be shown or not as well.

For example, I have this sub when a checkbox is clicked:

```
Private Sub MerT_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("GFATMEN").Activate
    If ActiveSheet.SeriesCollection.Count = 3 Then
        With ActiveChart
            If MerT = False Then
                .SeriesCollection(3).Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
                Call show_legend
            Else
                .SeriesCollection(3).Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
                Call show_legend
            End If
        End With
    End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It calls the other sub `show_legend`, that recreates the legend and formats it:

```
Sub show_legend()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("GFATMEN").Activate
    With ActiveChart
        .HasLegend = False
        .HasLegend = True
        .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
        .Legend.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
        .Legend.Font.Size = 10
        .Legend.Font.ForeColor.Brightness = 0.25
    End With
    If MerT = False Then ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries.Item(3).Delete
    If MerE = False Then ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries.Item(2).Delete
    If MerI = False Then ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries.Item(1).Delete
End Sub
```

The problem is that the code ALWAYS breaks from the `show_legend` sub an gets back to the previous sub whenever the line `.Legend.Font.ForeColor.Brightness = 0.25` is read. I've already put this line on a previous section, right after the `.HasLegend = True` line, and the same thing happens.

I couldn't find any answer that correlates to my problem. Thank you.

Comment: The checkboxes MerE and MerI are all similar subs to MerT.

Comment: Where did you get that code from? There is no `Font.ForeColor` property.

Comment: That line of code is probably throwing an error, which is being ignored as you have `On Error Resume Next` in the `MerT_Click` sub.

Comment: I wasn't paying attention to the On Error Resume Next, and no errors were being thrown. I changed the line `.Legend.Font.ForeColor.Brightness = 0.25` to `.Legend.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0.25` and now it works correctly. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like the code below:

```
With .Chart.Legend
    .Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
    .Font.Size = 10
    .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) '<-- modify the font color
    .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0.25 '<-- modify the font brightness
End With
```